# Long Double in Swift

Tags: swift, long-double

In C, there is a type called `long double`, which on my machine is 16-bytes (128-bit). Is there any way to store a `long double` in Swift? I've tried type aliases (`typedef`s) of `long double` from an Objective-C header, but it doesn't show up in Swift. And functions returning `long double` (`powl`, `sqrtl`) don't show up neither.

I know there's a `Float80` but that's only 80 bits, not 128 bits.

Comment: Are you sure is 128bits?  From the official docs: **long double** - extended precision floating point type. Does not necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754. **Usually 80-bit** x87 floating point type on x86 and x86-64 architectures.

Comment: Yes, `sizeof(long double)` returns `16`.

Comment: But how can I use `long double` functions in Swift?

Comment: Well, you can use Float80 or some custom integer types like https://github.com/Jitsusama/UInt128 or https://github.com/CryptoCoinSwift/UInt256

Comment: Can I use the C functions returning `long double` in Swift?

Comment: I tried to make a function that return a `long double` from C but Swift doesn't recognise the function, and it happens the same with a variable, so you can't use C long double in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a POWER processor, your 128 bit long double is actually an 80 bits extended precision number, plus 48 bit wasted.